# What is the right way to insulate a cinder block basement wall from inside when you only have room for furring strips and drywall?

Tags: insulation, basement

The wall behind the toilet in the bathroom I am renovating is cinder blocks

When this was finished the wall was first covered with some black paper (like tar paper but thinner) then they installed 1x4 furring strips and between these they put regular expanded polystyrene (the white stuff) and on top of the furring strips they added 1" Styrofoam and then drywall. There was no other framing on this small section behind the toilet and that was because in the old days (60's) the basement was not used for living but there was a service toilet there just in case you need. When the finished the  basement there was not enough room behind the toilet to do proper framing so the went with the above

Since the toilet I am installing is a bit longer and it requires 30cm (11 3/6") from the center of the drain to the wall I need to get thinner on insulation so I removed the insulation and I did not like what was behind

When they built the window frame  (see the picture) that is just above the toilet sit they left an empty and unfilled space under the base of the frame. I suspect that cold air went in and in time condensed and the humidity made it downward to the top side of the furring strips that are below that window. As a result these got rotten (no mold but the wood was crumbling)
Also the black paper that was there looked decayed -I can't say why but it looked thinner than the  same paper just below, lower on the same wall. Maybe it was rain water that got in one time ?! Not sure when and why the wood deteriorated

[image]

I decided that since I got this far I will redo it, it is an area of 65"x30" so not a big deal

What is the right way to do it ?
Should I continue to use that black paper ? What is the name of it ?
Should I add vapor barrier ? If yes where -near the wall or just behind the drywall
I am planning to use 1x4  pressure treated furring strips -is that OK ?

so to recap I should do these
-put back the back paper (if you guys think I should)
-put vapor barrier
-install furring strips (planning to use tapcon screws here)
-pub back the white polystyrene
-mold resistant drywall, green facing the inside of the bathroom

Comment: Basement walls below frost level do not need much insulation.  R-3/R-5 usually plenty with vapour barrier.   Good insulation needed from frost line to bottom of first floor.  Plastic vapour barrier is probably better than the paper, quite sure the white polystyrene is not good and probably against most codes, if it is the packing stuff.

Comment: where do I put the barrier? Next on the wall or on the furring strips and under the drywall?
Not sure if there is any 3/4" insulation that I can put there to replace the white stuff

Comment: If you really needed more space between the toilet and the wall you could replace the existing toilet with one that has a10" rough-in. This would give you 2 more inches of space.

Comment: @d.george is right. That's the wrong size toilet.

Comment: I think that what was there behind the toilet was over built, 
I would hate to have to return this toilet, it is this one https://www.ovedecors.com/pub/media/amasty/amfile/attach/IM_Stan_Tuva_2020-05-06.pdf and the cost was good (700CAD)

Comment: The quality and price make no difference if what you bought doesn't suit your needs. It means you simply failed to properly calculate all your needs before purchasing. Also, there's no picture here showing anything about a window frame.

Comment: It is what it is, the question still stands as long as I have identified a solution. Otherise we can go back to the point when I bought the house and say I bought one with the wrong bathroom that did not fit my needs :))))