# What should I fill with the void space left under the frame of my basement window?

Tags: windows

What should I fill with the void space left under the frame of my bathroom basement window? I discovered that space recently when I was trying to fix something else. Please see this thread [What is the right way to insulate a cinder block basement wall from inside when you only have room for furring strips and drywall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/235480/what-is-the-right-way-to-insulate-a-cinder-block-basement-wall-from-inside-when)

The traversal section of that space is a right triangl,e the legs are 3" and 1.5"

[image]

Comment: Please take a bigger picture to include the wall finish. This photo shows an area left unfinished for unknown reasons.

Comment: there is no finish under that -just cinder blocks. The other post I am referring to is where I am asking what should I put on that wall and it explains why the wall is empty now and what are my constrains

Comment: Then it is not a void space, it's an unfinished wall. Finish it with the rest of wall whatever method you are going to take. On the other post, you shall post a full-picture view of the wall, the cad drawing do not deliver the message well.

Comment: And do try to get a picture that's in focus. We get a general idea from this blurry pic, but it's hard to give a specific answer to a blurry question...